# Make and manipulate numpy arrays and use data with pyspark

Tags: numpy, pyspark

I'm running into a problem using hand-crafted test data in `pyspark.mllib.stat.KernelDensity`.  There is some sort of problem/difference between `numpy.float` and Python's generic `float` that shows up when using (some of) `pyspark`; specifically RDDs constructed with `numpy.float`'s breaks.

Is there a way I can create NumPy arrays in such a way that their elements are python floats and not `numpy.float`'s?

```
import pyspark
import pyspark.mllib.stat
import numpy
sc = pyspark.SparkContext("local", 'test2')
rdd1 = sc.parallelize([1.0, 2.0, 3.0])
rdd2 = sc.parallelize(numpy.arange(1.0, 4.0, 1.0))
(kd1, kd2) = pyspark.mllib.stat.KernelDensity(), pyspark.mllib.stat.KernelDensity()
kd1.setBandwidth(0.2)
kd1.setSample(rdd1)
kd2.setBandwidth(0.2)
kd2.setSample(rdd2)
x = numpy.arange(0, 5.0, 0.1)
y1 = kd1.estimate(x)
y2 = kd2.estimate(x)
```

## ^kd2.estimate fails

```
# can manually convert to "python float"
rdd2 = sc.parallelize([float(x) for x in numpy.arange(1.0, 4.0, 1.0)])
kd2.setSample(rdd2)
y2 = kd2.estimate(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing:

```
rdd2 = sc.parallelize(numpy.arange(1.0, 4.0, 1.0))
```

with

```
rdd2 = sc.parallelize(numpy.arange(1.0, 4.0, 1.0).tolist())
```

in the first code block.